getCharts suddenly stopped working in Google AppScripts
getCharts suddenly stopped working. Created a sheet with one chart and I'm getting this error all of a sudden:

bs.getCharts is not a function

const bs = ss.getSheetByName("Benefits Summary") 
function myFunction() {   
Logger.log(bs.getCharts()) 
} 

Adding some more details, this is the full script. I tested it even with a new spreadsheet.
const bs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Benefits Summary") 

Benefits summary has one chart on it.
function myFunction() {   
Logger.log(bs.getCharts()) 
} 

myFunction() still returns the same error when executed.

Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please take this opportunity to take the tour and learn how to ask, format the code, create a minimal reproducible example, etc.

ss is not defined.

I agree with @Tedinoz. In your original code, the variable bs is declared outside the scope of myFunction. The spreadsheet object ss is not defined within the same scope, which may result in bs being undefined when the function is called. To ensure that bs consistently references the correct sheet, it is necessary to define this variable within the function itself.

It's very likely that ss.getSheetByName("Benefits Summary") is returning null. This happens when spreadsheet doesn't contain a sheet with the specified name, in this case Benefits Summary.
To fix this, you have to look at your spreadsheet and ensure that there is a sheet named Benefits Summary or change the value used as the parameter of the getSheetByName method.
